# Wordpress Enfold contact form code snipped

Tags: wordpress, email, subject

I have WordPress version 5.4.2
enfold 4.7.6.1
using the default contact form would like to change the subject dynamically

what I'm trying to do is get the id from the URL into the subject field but only working partly

the subject only works the first part, "Enquiry About – " but $id is not showing
***UPDATE***
the id is from the URL example http://www.website.com/form?id=12

the code snippet is as follows

```
// Apply to fields named "Subject".
add_filter('avf_form_subject','avia_change_mail_subject', 10, 3);
function avia_change_mail_subject($subject, $new_post, $form_params) {
   
    if( is_page( 242 ) ):
    $id = $_GET['id'];
            //$subject = 'Enguiry About –  '$id;
            $subject = 'Enquiry About – ' . urldecode($id);
    
    endif;
    return $subject;
}
```

Comment: Where is `id` coming from? Are you submitting it in the form? Is it actually appearing in the url for this page (WP strips out reserved words)? Can you actually access the `$_GET` at the point where this hook is being called?

Comment: the id is coming from the URL please see the update in my question, above. if I make the id a shortcode I can get it to show on the page with no problem. but as soon as I add it to the above snippet, it does not work

Comment: Yes, but can you actually see it in the URL? As I said, WP strips reserved words out of the URLs, so it might be getting removed. As I also said, did you check that $_GET is accessible where this is being called? Did you try printing it outtp see if it had your ID or any other values? We don't have enough information to help based on what you've given us, so you need to do a bit more debugging to help narrow it down for us.

Comment: @FluffyKitten yes I can see it in the URL and if I do a shortcode I can see it on the screen but for some reason not on the subject line I have tried to use $_REQUEST as per below answer but still no luck.

Comment: And what do you get if you print $_GET (or $_REQUEST) to the screen? `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: @FluffyKitten then I get the id as it should be, but I cannot get the id into the subject field dynamically as per the code snippet I gave above.

Comment: Can you show us the exact output from the var_dump?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the page title of 242?

***Update***
Instead of `$_GET`, try `$_REQUEST`

```
add_filter('avf_form_subject','avia_change_mail_subject', 10, 3);
function avia_change_mail_subject($subject, $new_post, $form_params) {
   
    if( is_page( 242 ) ):
   
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $subject = 'Enquiry About –  $id;

    endif;

    return $subject;
}
```

Comment: sorry no, the URL has the id in it, example http://www.website.com/form?id=12. but I cannot get that so show in on the form subject line